# How to stream a Windows Azure Blob to the client using Node.js?

Tags: node.js, azure

I would like to send a Windows Azure Blob (an image) directly to the client ; I am trying this :

```
    blobService.getBlobToStream('images', req.url, res, function(err, blob) {
    if (!err) {
        res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': blob.contentType });
    } else {
        res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
        res.end(err);
    }
});
```

I am trying to pipe the Blob stream directly to the response stream ; should this work ? In Firefox, I get a message : "The image cannot be displayed because it contains errors". Looking at Firebug, the size of the image is 0.

Comment: Might be a silly question, but why do you want to stream the blob via your own hosted service? Why not just return the blob URL to the client or redirect them to the BLOB URL and let them stream it themselves by doing an HTTP GET. This would save you the hosting cost of buffering/re-streaming yourself. For large amounts of blob data this could save you lots of money.

Comment: Good point Mike, but I expect Tom is experimenting.

Comment: Yes, the idea is to transform the blob (an image) before streaming it back to the client (i.e. re-size it) ; thanks Richard!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems to work prefectly for me (if this is any help?):

```
var azure = require('azure');
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    var blobService = azure.createBlobService("xxx", "yyy", "blob.core.windows.net").withFilter(new azure.ExponentialRetryPolicyFilter());
    blobService.getBlobToStream('container', 'image.png', res, function(error){
        if(!error){
            res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'image/png'});
            res.end();
        }
        else
        {
            console.log('error');
            console.log(error);
            res.end();
        }
    });
}).listen(8080, "127.0.0.1");
```

**Update**

Just figured it out. `req.url` will have a leading slash (/). Which I'm guessing will not match your image filename.

Answer (score 0):

With azure-storage@2.10.2 I was getting errors about writing to the response after it was finalized. I also noticed that `getBlobToStream` handles the content type automatically.

```
const storage = require('azure-storage');
const blobService = storage.createBlobService(azureStorage.account, azureStorage.key); // if you want aren't using the same azure env vars

blobService.getBlobToStream(config.switchConfigStorage.container, 'image.png', res, function(error, blob){
  if(!error){ // blob retrieved
    console.log(blob); // good for debugging and possibly more processing
    res.end(); // no need to writeHead
  }else{
    console.log(error);
    res.end();
  }
});
```